# Disable truncate of select option text in samsung browser?

Tags: html, select, samsung-mobile, truncate, galaxy

is there a way to tell the Samsung "Internet" browser (the default browser on Samsung Galaxy S5, e.g.) to not truncate the text of long option names in html-select fields?

By default this text is truncated. The iOS optgroup-hack does not work here.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been [fiddling](https://github.com/poshaughnessy/options-truncate-test), but haven't found a way to hack around the character limit yet...

[image: Screenshow]

(Except rotating the phone for the wider landscape orientation!)

Perhaps you could have shorter titles in your options and make selecting one show/hide longer descriptions on your page?

If you have a good use case and think other browsers handle this better, you could also try adding a request on the Samsung dev forum: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/en